# Как оставить в строке только цифры 0-9, точки и запятые?

Tags: php

Желательно без регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

С регуляркой:

```
$str = "123456789mnbm0hfdec,hrthytr.";
$result = preg_replace("/[^,.0-9]/", '', $str);
echo $result;
```

Без регулярки:

```
$symbs =  array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ",", ".");

$callback = function ($a, $b) {

    if(in_array($b, $symbs))
        $a.=$b;
    return $a;
};

$str = "123456789mnbm0hfdec,hrthytr.";
$result = array_reduce(str_split($str), $callback, "");
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 3):

Если использовать функциональный подход к обработке строк, то логику фильтрации можно сделать компактной и относительно читаемой:

```
function filter_characters($str) {
    return implode('', array_filter(str_split($str), function($digit) {
        return ('.' === $digit || ',' === $digit || is_numeric($digit));
    }));
}

echo(filter_characters('123456789mnbm0hfdec,hrthytr.')); // 1234567890,.
```

[Рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/8LBEFh) на IDEOne.

**Замечание:**

Не знаю, чем вызвано желание провести замену без регулярного выражения, но в данном случае оно **не оправдано**. Выигрыша в скорости на такой простой задаче вы скорее всего не получите, зато существенно снизите читаемость кода.